# Best practice to implement static class inheritance? (singleton)

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, static, singleton

From php manual:

> [...] Static method calls are resolved at compile time.
>   When using an explicit class name the method is already identified completely and no
>   inheritance rules apply. If the call is done by self then self is translated to
>   the current class, that is the class the code belongs to.
>   Here also no inheritance rules apply [...]

..so im looking for a way to *emulate* the *standard* oop inheritance with static singleton.

Code explain better:

```
// Normal inheritance: my goal.
class Foo{
    public function test(){
        echo "Foo->test()\n";
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    public function other_test()
    {
        echo "Bar->other_test()\n";
    }
}


$obj = new Bar();
echo get_class($obj) . "\n";
$obj->test();
$obj->other_test();
/*
 Output:
Bar
Foo->test()
Bar->other_test()
*/


// How i would love to do:
class Foo2{
    public static function test2()
    {
        echo "Foo2::test2()\n";
    }

    // Singleton?
    public static $_instance;
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        if(is_null(self::$_instance))
        {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}

class Bar2 extends Foo2{
    public static function other_test2()
    {
        echo "Bar2::other_test2()\n";
    }
}

$obj2 = Bar2::get_instance();
echo get_class($obj2) . "\n";
$obj2::test2();
$obj2::other_test2();
/*
 Output:
Foo2
Foo2::test2()
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Foo2::other_test2()
*/

echo "\n-------\n";

// How im doing actually:
interface Foo3{
    public static function get_instance();
}

class Bar3 implements Foo3{
    // Singleton?
    public static $_instance;
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        if(is_null(self::$_instance))
        {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    public static function test3()
    {
        echo "Bar3::test3()\n";
    }
    public static function other_test3()
    {
        echo "Bar3::other_test3()\n";
    }
}


$obj3 = Bar3::get_instance();
echo get_class($obj3) . "\n";
$obj3::test3();
$obj3::other_test3();
/*
 Output:
Bar3
Foo3::test3()
Bar3::other_test3()
*/
```

The last 'way' force me to avoid the `get_instance` and static variables to be placed in the parent class, so I do not consider it as a best solution.. if for some reason my `get_instance()` function will change in the future, i dont want to edit all classes (*inheritance! inheritance! we all want inheritance!*)

So, is there a way or a best practices to solve this problem?

p.s: php5.3.2

Comment: [Don't use Singletons](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-join-new-project.html)

Comment: *(related)* [Who needs Singletons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323)

Comment: *(related)* [Static considered harmful](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links, i'll take a closer look to my design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Singleton pattern in PHP is something like this:

```
class Singleton {
     private static $instance = null;

     // Constructor is private, so class cannot be instantiazed from outside
     private function __construct() {
     }

     public static function getInstance() {
         if (static::$instance === null) {
              static::$instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return static::$instance;
     }

     public static function test() {
         echo 'Singleton::test()';
     }

     public function __sleep() {
         throw new Exception('Serialization is not alowed.');
     }

     public function __wakeup() {
         throw new Exception('Serialization is not alowed.');
     }

     public function __clone() {
         throw new Exception('Cloning is not alowed.');
     }
}
```

For you is important that keyword `static`, then this:

```
class B extends Singleton {
    public static function test2() {
         echo 'B::test2()';
    }
}

$b = B::getInstance();
B::test();
B::test2();
// Singleton::test()
// B::test()
```

Is this you looking for?

Comment: Mh yes, i was missing `new static();`.
Thanks mate, you made my day!

Comment: For complete answer is important to say, that late static binding feature comes with PHP 5.3 and more info can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php.

Comment: @Jakub Truneček Interesting re: late static binding, thanks for opening my eyes to it.